# Pasting a URL goes to the beginning of the sentence in Slack

Tags: slack

This is one damn annoying 'feature' (bug).
Whenever I paste a URL into Slack, it places the URL at the beginning of the sentence. Example:

```
https://www.google.com/hey bro, you should check out this cool link:
```

When I wanted something like:

```
hey bro, you should check out this cool link: https://www.google.com/
```

How can I get Slack to do what I want?